# Adding MKannotation to a mapview cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotationview

After I updated the Core data with the right value, i would like to add these value to the map view.
This the code that a I'd wrote for doing this it's this:

```
-(void)updateMapWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    int numberOfElementiOnMap = 0;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.ActiviIndicator startAnimating];

        [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];
    });
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
    if (predicate) {
        request.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude != nil) AND (longitude != nil)"]
                                                                                 ,predicate]];
    } else {
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude != nil) AND (longitude != nil)"];
    }

    //Get all different coordinate from core data.
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"latitude", @"longitude"]];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    // Execute the fetch
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *photos = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (NSDictionary *coordinateDic in photos) {
        NSPredicate *predicateToSend;
        if (predicate) {
            /* Get all pictures that corresponding to the coordinate inside the coordinateDic
             */
            predicateToSend = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude == %@) AND (longitude == %@)",
                                                                                    [coordinateDic valueForKey:@"latitude"], [coordinateDic valueForKey:@"longitude"]],predicate]];
        } else {
            predicateToSend = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(latitude == %@) AND (longitude == %@)",[coordinateDic valueForKey:@"latitude"], [coordinateDic valueForKey:@"longitude"]];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //get all picture with the same lautide and longitude that are specified on predicate
            NSArray *photos2 = [Photo pictureFromContext:self.context withPredicate:predicateToSend];
            //if the pictures are more then one, we add only one picture, and we write the number of pictures as a subtitle of the mkannotationview
            if ([photos2 count] > 1) {
                Photo *photo = [photos2 lastObject];
                photo.photoDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"album with %lu picures",(unsigned long)[photos2 count]];
                if (photo) {
                  //  [self.mapView addAnnotation:photo];
                }                
            } else { //add the only pictures
                if ([photos2 firstObject]) {
                   [self.mapView addAnnotation:[photos2 firstObject]];
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On this code i basically retrieve the value that in need from core date, and then add it to the map.

The objects that I'm adding to the map are obviously conform to the `<MKAnnotation>` protocol. I got the error on the `[self.mapView addAnnotation:[photos2 firstObject]];`line. The strange fact is that some object that i get from core date are correctly added to the map. I tried to debug the code by enabling the NSZombie but i got the same error. I also check the coordinate and everything it's all right. The only difference that i found while I'm debugging the code it's this:
The object that are added correctly to the maps looks like this in the debugger:

[image]

Instead when i get the error, the object that I'm adding to the map looks like this on the simulator:

[image]

and when i print the content of: 0 i get this:

```
Printing description of *([0]->[0]):
(Photo_Photo_) [0] = {}
```

which it's look like a pointer to an empty entity.
do you have any idea of how can i solve this?
Thanks

Comment: When you say "some object that I get from core date are correctly added to the map", are you saying that you have successful map annotations being presented on the MapView, and this error is only occurring some of the time?

Comment: Yes, the normal behavior it's this:
Open the app --> switch to the map view --> add mkannotation to the map from core data (everything works fine) ---> update core data ---> update the map with the new core data value --> crash

Comment: So I'm not 100% sure, but the problem could be that you are attempting to add the same object (albeit modified) to the map view without first removing the annotation. Try removing the annotation from the map before adding it back on, and see if that helps.

Comment: before adding the annotations i use the [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations]; method for remove all annotations on the map (see the code)

Comment: sorry, missed that part. It could still have to do with that, though, since you're dispatching that asynchronously, which means the order in which things are occurring could be messed up. Why are you removing annotations in a dispatch block?

Comment: i remove or add the annotation an main thread and i get the information from core data in a second thread, i think there is nothing wrong with this. I also tried to remove the annotation in ViewWillAppear but the result it's still the same

Comment: I am having a very similar issue. I receive the updates with notifications from the NSFetchResultsController, if i try to update the map with the updated MKAnnotation y receive a BAD_ACCESS. I also didn't find any zombie objects with instruments.

Comment: I think the problem is with the coordinates. All coordinates seem to be fine, i even added a call to CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid before adding it to the map, but, if i hardcode all the pins to location (1.1,1.1) for example, all works great. Also, in lldb, when i have my annotation type as id, the coordinates return garbage. I have to cast it to my type ( [((MapPin *)obj) coordinates]) in order to receive the correct coordinates. I hope this can help im some way. This is getting me crazy.

Comment: @bilby91 It seems that you're right, when i change my coordinate to (1.1,1.1) all works fine. But I still can't find what it's the problem... It look like something it's corrupted, but i cant understand when and why this happen.

Comment: @Max_Power89 Are you using NSFetchResultsController ?

Comment: no, I just retrieve the data from Core data and add it on the map

Comment: If you have any insight on this issue let me know. @bilby91 in Twitter.

Comment: With how many annotations are you working ? I suspect that this could be caused by high memory usage.

Comment: @bilby91 around 200, 250 annotation

Comment: @Max_Power89 It's actually a bug in Map Kit at the end. Try it with 100 pins and you will see that is works. I posted a bug report to apple and i'll upload a repo to github with a project that reproduces the bug.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the bug report Apple told me the solution for my problem. The problem was that i was updating the coordinate in a non KVO compliant way. I store the properties like you, with latitude and longitude. Try adding this on your Photo class.

```
- (void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"latitude"] || [key isEqualToString:@"longitude"]) { [self willChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"]; }
    [super willChangeValueForKey:key];
}

- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"latitude"] || [key isEqualToString:@"longitude"]) { [self didChangeValueForKey:@"coordinate"]; }
    [super didChangeValueForKey:key];
}
```

Hope this helps.